# Enviar un arreglo con datos y buscar en mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Relicé un método para buscar datos en mi base de datos `MongoDB`, el cual recibe un valor y devuelve una lista con documentos.

Ahora deseo, en vez de enviar un sólo valor, enviar un arreglo con valores y que mi método busque documentos para cada valor de la lista, en la base de datos.

Me gustaría usar el mismo método. Si es que me pueden ayudar, se los agradecería.

```
list: async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let valor = req.query.valor;
        const reg = await models.ProductoMaria.find({
                $or: [{
                    'codigoAntiguoBibliotecaria': new RegExp(valor, 'i')
                }, {
                    'eliminar': 1
                }]
            }, {
                createdAt: 0
            }).populate('tipoProducto', {
                nombre: 1
            })
            .sort({
                'createdAt': 1
            });
        res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Ocurrió un error'
        });
        next(e);
    }
},
```

Comment: ¿con arreglo te refieres a objeto?

Comment: un array con numero, por ejemplo este list acepta valores numericos y los busca en mongodb, lo que deseo es enviar un array con 4 valores numericos y que me traiga la informacion de esos 4 valores

Comment: Perdona jimmy pero no entiendo bien tu pregunta. Quieres hacer un método dinámico que acepte exactamente que como parametro. 

Por lo que veo en el codigo que enviaste hay un $or con dos condiciones. ¿Querrías mantener esas condiciones?

Comment: Perdon por no explicarme muy bien, pero en vez de aceptar un solo parametro el metodo, deseo que acepte un array o arreglo de datos, manteniendo las condiciones de los $or de mongoDB. Agradezco el interes y la ayuda

Comment: Lo que deseo hacer es comparar 2 libros en una tabla con sus caracteristicas y los valores de unicos de cada libro y utilizo este metodo para mostrar las caracteristicas de un libro solo, y recorro el arreglo productos con un for para colocar los valores en una tabla ListarDetalles(tagProducto) {
      let me = this;
      let header = {
        Token: this.$store.state.token
      };
     axios
        .get("valores/list?valor=" + String(tagProducto))
        .then(function(response) {
          me.productos = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {});
    },

Comment: Jimmy, podrías detallar un poco más tus colecciones y que quieres hacere con este método exactamente con un ejemplo de tu código? 

Para poder ayudarte necesito entender bien el problema.

Comment: Hola buenos dias, aqui en el siguiente enlace esta el proyecto entero  para que puedas verlo. para inciarlo debes abrir 2 terminarles el primero ingresando a la carpeta sistema y iniciando el con el siguiente comando "npm run dev" y la siguiente terminal ingresando a la carpeta vue y escribir el siguiente  comando en la terminal "npm run serve"  este es el link del proyecto  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cXEGcOt7UVcvm4a_dwDsn0Jz5WBw3DrH/view?usp=sharing     Agradezco cada ayuda y por el interes demostrado

Comment: Jimmy, he solicitado acceso a tu proyecto. Mañana cuando tenga un hueco le echo un ojo y te echo una mano ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Que campo debe coincidir con el arreglo que quieres mandar? En general puedes usar `find({miCampo: {$in:miArreglo}}`

Comment: Hola muy buenas tardes, deseo enviar un array que en su interior contenga 4 codigoAntiguoBibliotecaria, lo he intentado con  find({codigoBibliotecaria:{$in: librosCodigo}})    y solo coge el primer valor y los otros valores no los consulta. muchas gracias por su interes y ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que separes la lógica del enrutador de express a otra capa y función.

Para este caso te recomendaría hacer un find mediante post, para que puedas pasar un objeto mediante el body y así puedas tener un list un poco más completo, si es que necesitas pasar muchos campos para la búsqueda y para evitar problemas con los arrays mandándolos por queryString.

Puedes crear un fichero que se llame route.js con las rutas de express:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const controller = require('./controller');


router.post('/list', controller.list);
```

Tu controller puedes dejarlo más limpio, moviendo la lógica de bbdd a otra capa:

```
const DAO = require('./dao.js');
module.exports.list = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const results = await DAO.list(req.body);
        res.status(200).json(reg);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Ocurrió un error'
        });
        next(e);
    }
};
```

Un fichero para las operaciones de base de datos, puedes llamarlo DAO o como quieras.

```
module.exports.list = async(objetoDeConsulta) => {

    //Aquí implementas la lógica para recorrer tu objeto de consulta, 
    //tendrás que saber los campos que vienen de que tipo son para aplicar un filtrado u otro, si usas $eq, si usas $in...

    const condicionDeBusqueda = dameCondicionesDeBusqueda(objetoDeConsulta);
    const results = await models.ProductoMaria.find(
        {
            $and: [
                condicionDeBusqueda,
                $or: [
                    {
                        'codigoAntiguoBibliotecaria': new RegExp(valor, 'i')
                    }, 
                    {
                        'eliminar': 1
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        {
            createdAt: 0
        }
    )
    .populate('tipoProducto', {nombre: 1})
    .sort({'createdAt': 1});

    return results;
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)